# How to change icons in ReorderableListView.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm making a list, but I wanted to make a list that changes the order to drag and drop, so I made a list using ReorderableListView.builder.

I want to change the "=" shape on the right side of each widget to another icon, or adjust the position.
What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3pT7.png)

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items!.elementAt(index);
            return GestureDetector(
              key: Key("$index"),
               onLongPress: () {
              ....
              },
              onTap: () {
              ....
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                    ),
                  ],
                  border: Border.all(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 60, 183, 255),
                ),
                height: 60,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        items!.elementAt(index).split("|")[0],
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                       ....
                      },
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.delete_forever_rounded,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: items?.length ?? 0,
          onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
            setState(() {
              if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
                newIndex -= 1;
              }
              final item = items!.removeAt(oldIndex);
              items!.insert(newIndex, item);
              saveData();
            });
          },
        ),
```

I've tried googling, but I can't find a way to get rid of the icon but change it.

Answer (score 0):

Set `buildDefaultDragHandles` `false` on the `ReorderableListView`. This will remove the default handle.

Then, in your `Row`, wherever you want the icon, `ReorderableDragStartListener` with the `Icon` as the `child`. This will allow the item to be dragged.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
ReorderableListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (int index = 0; index < items!.length; index += 1)
            ListTile(
              key: Key('$index'),
              tileColor: Colors.transparent,
              title: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 5,
                  top: 5,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                      ),
                    ],
                    border: Border.all(),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 60, 183, 255),
                  ),
                  height: 60,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 5,
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.table_rows_rounded,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onLongPress: () {
                            ...
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              items!.elementAt(index).split("|")[0],
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          ....
                        },
                        child: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.delete_forever_rounded,
                            size: 35,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              onTap: () {
                ....
              },
            ),
        ],
        onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
          setState(() {
            if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
              newIndex -= 1;
            }
            final String item = items!.removeAt(oldIndex);
            items!.insert(newIndex, item);
            saveData();
          });
        },
      ),
```